# How to select lowest ordered items in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that looks like this:

[image]

When someone selects Yes in Column A, I want to take the three lowest ordered Yes responses (order determined by Column C) and add those three answers to G4, G5, and G6 in lowest to highest order.

So, with the screenshot above, G4 would have 'Answer 1' (this is the lowest order item that was marked 'Yes' in Column A), and G5 would be 'Answer 3', and G6 would be 'Answer 4'.

I have no idea how to do this - any suggestions, and if possible, a sample sheet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to Web Apps StackExchange!](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) It would be best if you could share a dummy sheet with realistic data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(A2:D, "SELECT D WHERE A = 'Yes' ORDER BY C LIMIT 3",0)
```

This filters out all rows with "No" in the first column then sorts by the C column (which isn't necessary for your data, but if it's ever rearranged then it can reorder.) It then limits it to 3 rows.

Comment: Perfect, that works, thanks!